Developing projects using QGIS and QField with QFieldCloud sync
I am quite new to QGIS and QField, but with all the documentation and videos, I have made a good start. However, I think I must have missed it in the documentation for QField and QFieldCloud, but I cannot get my head around the proper workflow for what I want.
I am creating projects to be used in the field to record several kinds of data, both tracks and points. I am creating attribute forms in QGIS with relations, tabs, constraints, etc. I already managed to get them to do what I want in QGIS.
Then I want to test them in QField to see if they function the way I want to in the field.
Inevitably, I have made some mistakes or some ideas don't work as well as hoped in the field. So I need to make changes to the layers with the attribute forms. And then push these changes to the project in the cloud so the people in the field can test them.
I have tried many different things, but cannot seem to get this process to work. Especially the fact that uploading the project to the cloud (using the QField plugin) creates a copy of the project. I then don't know whether I should make subsequent changes in that cloud-copy or in the original projectfile.
And what if the projects are being used to collect real data in the field and I want to make a small change to an attribute form, or add a field, etc., how can I make sure that the already collected data are safe and the people in the field are getting the update in the form?
